# Is recursive dependency injection graph is bad?

Tags: php, recursion, dependency-injection

given this code:

```
class Test1
{
    private $test3;

    public function setTest3(Test3 $test3)
    {
        $this->test3 = $test3;
    }
}

class Test2
{
    private $test1;

    public function setTest1(Test1 $test1)
    {
        $this->test1 = $test1;
    }
}

class Test3
{
    private $test2;

    public function setTest2(Test2 $test2)
    {
        $this->test2 = $test2;
    }
}

$test1 = new Test1();
$test2 = new Test2();
$test3 = new Test3();
$test1->setTest3($test3);
$test2->setTest1($test1);
$test3->setTest2($test2);
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($test1);echo '</pre><hr>';
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($test2);echo '</pre><hr>';
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($test3);echo '</pre><hr>';
```

var_dump() even echoes *recursion*. Although it works well, is that a bad sign?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a code review question

Comment: @Andreas If this was a question on Code Review, I'd close it.

Comment: @Peilonrayz it's certainly off topic here to in my opinion.